# Use @DataProvider with Jmockit

Tags: java, testng, jmockit

I'm using Testng 6.8.5 and Jmockit 1.4 for my project. I want to use testng `@DataProvider` with Jmockit `@Mocked` annotation with test parameter level.

```
@Test
public void testRemove(@Mocked Creator) throws Exception {
   //Test Code
}
```

I want to use above test with different data sets (using `@DataProvider`), but when I change the method signature to:

```
public void testRemove(@Mocked Creator creator, int id, String name)
```

where `id` and `name` are provied by the DataProvider, TestNG fails saying that the DataProvider only provides two parameters, not three.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: That should work fine - what problem have you encountered?

Comment: Problem is using @Mocked annotation with @DataProvider params. For Ex `public void testRemove(@Mocked Creator creator, int id, String name){` . Here id and name comes from dataproider. For this Testng fails test specifying @DataProvider does not give 3 params, which is true.

Comment: I see - I suppose you could mock the creator within the method, in an expectations block for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mocked object must be a fied of the test class.

```
public class UserTest {

    @Mocked
    Creator creator;


    @DataProvider(name = "my data provider")
    public Oject[][] dataProvider() {
    //code data proviver
    }


    @Test(dataProvider = "my data provider")
    public void testRemove(int id, String name) {
        new Expectations() {{
            creator.doSomething(...);
            result = expectedResult;

            //other expectation
        }};
        //other test code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following (I tested it with TestNG 6.8.21 and Jmockit 1.20, it mocks the object correctly):

```
public class UserTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "creatorProvider")
    public Oject[][] dataProvider() {
      return new Object[][] {{null, 1 "t1"}, {null, 2, "t2"}};
    }


    @Test(dataProvider = "creatorProvider")
    public void testRemove(@Mocked final Creator creator, int id, String name) {
        new Expectations() {{
            creator.doSomething(id, name); result = expectedResult;
        }};

        //other test code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring a @Mocked class field, you can also declare a local @Mocked object with [dynamic partial mocking](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#dynamicPartial).

Partial mocking only mocks the methods you record though (not explicitly mocked methods will not be mocked; they will use their default implementation).